# Random generated array push

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to test feature to only push to this array 10% of the time, I've come up with a solution that works but is there a more dynamic way of handling this?

This is what I came up with:

```js
const random = []

const randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 9); 
console.log(randomNumber)

if (randomNumber === 5) {
random.push({
title: "testing"
})

console.log(random, 'testing push')
} else {
console.log('not this time')
}
```

I'm selecting 10 possibly numbers, if the number equals 5 then push to the array, if not don't. This would make it a 1/10 chance if it pushing it to the array.

Is it possible to create a more dynamic solution of saying 10% of the time push the object to the array?

Comment: If you want exactly 10% of the time, create a counter which increases by 1 each iteration. and use a remainder in a conditional statement. So... counter++, if(counter%10===0)...

Answer (score 3):

I would say you can simplify your formula:

```
const percentage=10;

if (Math.random() <== percentage/100){
    //Should be executed 10% of the time 

}
```